# UltraGrid get all cells

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I can't find a way to get **all** cells in a `UltraGrid`. I want to get through them all in a foreach loop.

Is there a way to get them all ?

Comment: Going through all cells of each row doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through all the [`Rows`](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~Rows.html) of the grid, then through all the [`Cells`](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow~Cells.html) of the row:

```
foreach(var row in myGrid.Rows)
{
   foreach(var cell in row.Cells)
   {
      // Do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think thats what i'm going to do. I just wanted to see if there was a cell collection instead of looping once through all rows and then through all cells –

Comment: `row.Cells` is a collection of UltraGridCell.

Comment: @Steve - Yes, it is. Is that an issue?

Comment: @Steve - I think the OP meant they were hoping for a direct `.Cells` on the grid, which would allow iteration on all of them, instead of going through `Rows` then `Cells`.

Comment: @Oded exactly I though a double for each loop was a bit "overkill" for  a collection that could have been on the "first layer" but still I guess there is a good reason.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk before using this approach you should know the implications of looping through all of the cells.  UltraGridCell objects are created as they are needed and if you loop through all of them this will increase the memory usage of the application.  Depending on your needs it may be more appropriate to loop through the data in the list you are bound to or use the GetCellValue method of the UltraGridRow to get the cell values.  More details can be found in the documentation: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinGrid_Performance_Guide.html

Comment: @alhalama Thanks I actually knew about this which is why I was looking for another solution. I'll take a look at the link ! :)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk what is it that you are trying to accomplish by looping through the cells?  I may be able to provide a better suggestion if I know more details.